# Remove /sites/25/ from image URLS

Tags: htaccess

I am running multisite with subdomains.  I'd like to manipulate the image path for the "espanol" subdomain only.

Here is the current image path (example):

```
https://espanol.xxx.xx.xx.xxx.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2016/08/2008-SKYTRAK-10054-160036928-2f.jpg
```

Here is what is needed:

```
https://espanol.xxx.xx.xx.xxx.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2008-SKYTRAK-10054-160036928-2f.jpg
```

Can this be done for only the "espanol" subdomain with .htaccess?

Comment: What is the actual filesystem location of these files? Have you already updated WordPress to the desired URL path?

Comment: The actual filestream location is the one that I am redirecting to.  “Updating” WordPress is not relevant due to the fact that this is a customization and not a bug per say.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to *internally rewrite* the URL, rather than *externally redirect* the request...

To *rewrite* the image URL-path to remove `/sites/25` for the `espanol` subdomain only then try something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^espanol\.
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads)/sites/25/(\d{4}/\d\d/[\w-]+\.jpg)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

Following `/sites/25/`, the source URL-path is assumed to be of the form of 4-digits, slash, 2-digits, slash and any number of *word* characters (`\w`) including the hyphen and then `.jpg`. (`\w` being a shorthand character class for `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.)

> **UPDATE:** I also need the "espanol" subdomain removed during the rerwrite.

You can't do that with a simple *rewrite*. You can't URL-rewrite across hosts. You would either need to configure your server as a *reverse proxy* and proxy the request using mod_proxy. Or implement this as an external redirect instead.

For example, as an external redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^espanol\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads)/sites/25/(\d{4}/\d\d/[\w-]+\.jpg)$ https://%1/$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

This does assume you don't have other domains that share the same "espanol" subdomain.

The `%1` backreference (note the `%` prefix) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* holds the hostname less the `espanol.` prefix.

Change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only after you have tested that this works OK for you. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can making testing problematic.

Comment: I have not tried this yet but wanted to mention that I also need the "espanol" subdomain removed during the rerwrite.

Comment: Ah, that does somewhat change the question. You can't remove the subdomain with a simple rewrite. If the request does not resolve with the subdomain then you will need to either implement a reverse proxy or change this to a "redirect". I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  The image actually lives at https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2008-SKYTRAK-10054-160036928-2f.jpg  for example